# Making a struct member Encodable

Tags: swift

I'm trying to JSON encode a single struct member, I know the member conforms to the Encodable protocol, but the compiler complains about it, saying that "Protocol 'Schema' as a type cannot conform to 'Encodable'". the code looks something like this:

```swift
protocol Schema { }

struct Foo {
    let a: Schema
}

f = F(a: a)
let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(f.a)
```

In this case, I know for a fact that `a` does in fact conform to `Encodable`, however, I don't know how to enforce this in the `Foo` struct. I tried changing it so that `Foo.a: Encodable` but then it complains that protocol `Encodable` cannot conform to itself.

After reading about this I understand where the error is coming from, there is no way for the compiler to actually be sure that `Foo.a` conforms to `Encodable` because downstream struct may add members that are non-codable, at least that is how I understand it.

However, I can't figure out how to tell it that `Foo.a` conforms to codable.

I tried this: `guard let x = f.a as? Encodable else { }` but that just results in the same error.

So basically what I want to know is if there is any way to require that implementers of the `Schema` protocol also conform to `Encodable`. Currently, all the implementers of `Schema` are structs, I think I could solve this by changing them to classes and letting them inherit from a base class that is `Encodable` but I'm not sure, and I would prefer to use structs.

Comment: Make it `let a: Schema & Encodable` or `protocol Schema: Encodable {}`, and do something similar to the `AnyEncodable` in the second half of [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67120403/5133585).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, if you make an answer out of this I can upvote it.